# jQuery tablesorter - sorting by rows and columns, not just columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have this problem. I have a big table with categories in THEAD and in TBODY I have authors of articles. When I apply tablesorter on this table, I can sort it by columns

But I want to sort it by rows too, so I can tell, how many articles author has in which category. Is it possible?

Oh I forgot, I am using this tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the information you've provided but it sounds like you need grouping. You want to count the number of articles for each author and then sort authors by article count.

If that is the case, and it's not possible to do the grouping in the database, jOrder (http://github.com/danstocker/jorder) will be your best bet.

Anyway, it would help if you provided some more details on how your table looks like now and how you want it to look when you "sort by rows".

Comment: NP :) Feel free to contact me (on GitHub or jorder.net) if you have further questions on how to group & sort using jOrder.